# equivalence groupyby().unique() for categorical values in PySpark

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My data is as follow.
[It has three attributes: location, date, and student_id.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kvSc.png)

In Pandas, I can do

groupby(['location','date'])['student_id'].unique()

to see each location, in different date, which students go to study there at the same time.

My question is how to do the same groupby in PySpark to extract the same information? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use collect_set in pyspark to get it done,

```
 df.groupby('location','date').agg(F.collect_set('student_id')).show()

 +--------+----------+-----------------------+
 |location|      date|collect_set(student_id)|
 +--------+----------+-----------------------+
 |   18250|2015-01-04|               [347416]|
 |   18253|2015-01-02|       [167633, 188734]|
 |   18250|2015-01-03|               [363796]|
 +--------+----------+-----------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data has rows in the form:

```
(location, date, student_id)
```

You can do:

```
data
.map(lambda row: (row[0:2], {row[2]})
.reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a.union(b))
.collect()
```